# Why would you delete an import at the end of a file?

Tags: python, import, styles, del

I was reading Mitsuhiko's (creator of flask, jinja2, werkzeug,...) [code for the flask website](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-website) which he open sourced recently.
In the `websiteconfig.py` file at the root, the code goes like this:

```
import os

_basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = False

SECRET_KEY = 'testkey'
DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(_basedir, 'flask-website.db')
DATABASE_CONNECT_OPTIONS = {}
ADMINS = frozenset(['http://lucumr.pocoo.org/'])

WHOOSH_INDEX = os.path.join(_basedir, 'flask-website.whoosh')
DOCUMENTATION_PATH = os.path.join(_basedir, '../flask/docs/_build/dirhtml')

del os
```

I was simply wondering **why he deletes this os import**?
I am looking to improve my code style, so I get that it's to save up memory space, but how important is this really on modern systems? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It helps clear up the namespace. By doing this, you can then do:

```
from websiteconfig import *
```

And you'll get all of the configuration values without bringing `os` into the importing scope.

Comment: Oh so it's more to prevent future, inheritance issues?

Comment: Not really inheritance per se, as that only applies with classes :) It's not essential, but it can be helpful at times to keep the amount of namespace "pollution" low. It's pretty much just a personal style preference, IMO, and as mentioned, I'd probably only use it where a `*` import would be useful.